# Adding a new instruction to a MIPS

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates, mips

heyy, I study software so i'm absolutely new when it comes to drawing electrical circuits and I need to add a new instruction to This MIPS machine here

[image]

The new instruction i have to add jt - jump table - is an instruction which makes it possible to go to the address indicated by a value in memory at the address indicated by two registers:

> `jt rs, rt # PC := mem[ R[rs] + R[rt] * 8 ]`

Its encoding is as follows:
• Instruction [31-26]: Operation code for jt

• Instruction [25-21]: rs registry number

• Instruction [20-16]: rt registry number

• Instruction [15-11]: 0

• Instruction [10-6]: 0

• Instruction [5-0]: 0x20

Can someone explain to a complete beginner (me) the process to add an instruction like this one on the diagram? Thanks for your time.

Comment: looks like there's nothing to add to the diagram at that level, but you'll need to push in to the controleur to ad some microcode.

Comment: @Neil_UK hey thanks for your response, it's an exercice from my teacher so i think they are some parts missing in order to make jt works. Can you explain what you mean by push in and microcode?

Comment: I think Neil means the hardware already can add, and shift (to scale by 8). Your task is to write the bit-patterns to select the needed hardware behaviors. Note you may need to use the various busses to pass around the variables. ============================================= How to move the variables into the adder? you must explore and understand that, using bits from the controller

Comment: Since this is homework you should really talk to your teacher to find out if there is something missing. This isn't Chegg...we don't hand out homework solutions here.